# PHP - MySQL - Search date, count rows that have that date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query which pulls a count from a DB by searching by date and it's not returning what it should.  There's 3 records in the database, type Date, with the date 2012-04-06.

$day is echoing out on the page as that date, so I know it's passing into the function right.

```
$countrows = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table WHERE startDate LIKE '" . $day. "'";
$countresult = mysql_query($countrows);
$count = mysql_fetch_row($countresult);
$finalcount = $count[0];
```

Just stuck, need a second, third, fourth set of eyes.  I'm obviously missing something.

ALSO: I'd like the count to come out as an integer so I can do math with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the step of `$values = mysql_fetch_row($countresult)`. Your `$countresult` is a variable of type `MYSQL_QUERYRESULT` (or somesuch) rather than an array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php

Apart from that, DB queried values will always be strings first in PHP. just do a `$var = (int)$var;` if you want to make sure it's a number.

Comment: Updating original to show the real field name of startDate instead.

Comment: It just echoes out 'array' now

Comment: Updated question to have the fetch row as well.

Comment: `$finalcount` echoes 'array'? That would be strange since DB values are never arrays.

Comment: Yeah I know.  I'm really confused.

Comment: Nevermind - I'm so f'ing stupid.  i didn't swap out the variable name to the fetch and have been staring at it for two hours and just kept overlooking it - it's late.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `LIKE` for date comparisons. You can just do

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM test_table WHERE startDate = '" . $day. "'";
```

And as Armatus points out, you need to call `mysql_fetch_row` as well.